# C# alternative to the VB code

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have this VB code

```
Try
    For i = 0 To OutData.NumMerids - 1
        With OutData.MeridData(0)
            .NumCurves = InStepFiveData.ConvexSurfaceData.MultiCurveData.NumOzCurves + InStepFiveData.ConvexSurfaceData.MultiCurveData.NumLenticularCurves
            ReDim .CurveData(.NumCurves - 1)
        End With
    Next
    ...
```

I want to generate similar C# code. I used some logic and deducted the code below.

```
try
{
    for (i = 0; i <= OutData.NumMerids - 1; i++)
    {
        //   var _with25 = OutData.MeridData[0];
        OutData.MeridData[0].NumCurves =(short) (InStepFiveData.ConvexSurfaceData.MultiCurveData.NumOzCurves + InStepFiveData.ConvexSurfaceData.MultiCurveData.NumLenticularCurves);
        // ERROR: Not supported in C#: ReDimStatement
        Array.Resize(ref OutData.MeridData[0].CurveData, OutData.MeridData[0].NumCurves - 1);
    }
    ...
}
```

Just want to know that am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Please consider posting this on Code Review. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Bear in mind that while `Array.Resize` appears to just resize your array it actually creates a copy behind the scenes effectively changing the reference to your array. in this case, what that means is if you've previously assigned `OutData.MeridData[0].CurveData` to some other variable, it will still be pointing to a non-resized array.

Comment: Don't subtract 1 in your `Resize` call. C# array dimensions and most framework functions work in terms of *lengths*, VB array declarations work in terms of *bounds*. Which usually means that comparable code between C# and VB involving arrays, when at least one of them is using language constructs (rather than library functions) requires adjusting the value by one.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever perfect ! what about the converted code . is this conversion correct. Array.Resize(ref OutData.MeridData[0].CurveData ?

Comment: Does the code work as expected?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error lies in the Array.Resize statement ; more specifically in the size given.

In VB.Net you give the last index of the array where in C# you give the length of the array
So there is a shift of 1 between the two.

```vb
ReDim .CurveData(.NumCurves - 1)
' equivalent to
ReDim .CurveData(0 To .NumCurves - 1) ' length is (.NumCurves - 1) - 0 + 1 = .NumCurves
```

This comes from the fact that in VB6 you could have an array indexed in other base than 0 (notably the 1 indexed collection) and so that was valid (***it isn't in VB.Net***)

```vb
Dim someArray(-4 To 5) As Integer ' declares an array of 10 integer indexed from -4 to 5
```

<s>Back to your code you just need to give the size</s>

```cs
//Array.Resize(ref OutData.MeridData[0].CurveData, OutData.MeridData[0].NumCurves - 1);
// replaced by
Array.Resize(ref OutData.MeridData[0].CurveData, OutData.MeridData[0].NumCurves);
```

As for the comment given by Ashwin Nair ; `ReDim` has the same behaviour (I wouldn't be surprise ReDim uses Array.Resize internally in .Net)

## Edit :

As Dave said in it's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38529365/4925216) Array.Resize is the translation of `Redim Preserve` not `Redim` (which wipes the data away)

Comment: so Do i need to to it everywhere where I see array declaration  ?

Comment: @Apoorv Chances are that yes probably you'll need it for each array declaration `Dim`, resize `ReDim` or copy `ReDim Preserve` ; it's the same logic for the `for` loop ; in VB.Net you have to put `bound - 1` when in C# you can juste put `< bound` because of the strict comparison instead of a comparison **or equal**

Comment: You are confusing 'ReDim' with 'ReDim Preserve'.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas yeah I tend to avoid both ReDim form and was more focused about the size thing I forgot to think about conservation or not of the items

Answer (score 2):

You (and the accepted answer) are confusing 'ReDim' with 'ReDim Preserve'.
Your 'ReDim' statement is just converted using a 'new' statement to create the array:

```
OutData.MeridData[0].CurveData = new Foo[OutData.MeridData[0].NumCurves];
```

(The type of 'CurveData' is unknown to me, so I used 'Foo' - you'll have to replace with the appropriate type).

Answer (score 1):

A few things you can correct/improve:

C# `for` loops require you to declare the loop variable.

`for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {`

This might not be an issue if you've already declared `i` somewhere above, but I would recommend keeping the iterator variable limited to the scope of the loop if possible.

As a substitution for VB's `With` I would use a local variable.  (I believe this is what `With` actual does behind the scenes.)  It looks like you commented that out for some reason.  Every time you reference `OutData.MeridData[0]` or `InStepFiveData.ConvexSurfaceData.MultiCurveData` you have to deference several objects, and depending on the structure ofthose objects that could be inefficient.  Plus it's hard to read.

@Dave Doknjas got the `Redim` substitution part right, you just need to use a constructor.  `Redim` actually throws out the old array and creates a new one, so its name is actually a bit misleading.  To `Redim Preserve` you would need to use `Array.Copy` to move values from the old array to the new one.

```
try {
   for (var i = 0; i <= OutData.NumMerids - 1; i++) {
      var meridData = OutData.MeridData[0];
      var curveData = InStepFiveData.ConvexSurfaceData.MultiCurveData;
      meridData.NumCurves = (short)(curveData.NumOzCurves + curveData.NumLenticularCurves);
      meridData.CurveData = new Foo[meridData.NumCurves];
   }
}
```

Comment: What to use instead of Redim? I am using Array.Reize() .

Comment: .NET arrays cannot actually be resized, so any function that looks like its resizing one is actually creating a new array, and possibly copying the contents of the original array over.  I would just manually create the new array yourself. `new MyClass[100]`